# C# ASP.Net adding online web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am trying to add online SOAP web service to my web application in Visual Studio. I tried several tutorials but most of the tutorials focus on creating server on local host.

In my web application, I want to get all the countries from web service using following url.
http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCountries

It provides following SOAP request and response.

Request

```
POST /country.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCountries xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET" />
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCountriesResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <GetCountriesResult>string</GetCountriesResult>
    </GetCountriesResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How I added web service reference is,

In visual studio, I clicked in my project -> Add -> Service Reference -> Advanced Tab -> Add Web Reference -> entered URL of web service(http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx).

[image]

My problem is how to get the countries from the web service. I tries several methods, but no success.
How to call the service from my asp file.

Comment: have you tried doing it with any other type of web service..? does it have to be soap..? can you use Linq to Sql web services.. soap is so dang gone OLD and out dated.. `WCF web services` is easier

Comment: Well, my requirements say that I must use SOAP.

Comment: I understand is this something that your boss want's written in SOAP because you generate valid XML via a web service by bypassing `SOAP` anyway I think that your issues deals with improperly consuming / instantiating the web service and or Proxy

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the class that was built and then call a member function:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient Client = new ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient("countrySoap12");

    String Countries = Client.GetCountries();
}
```

Cool, the string returned looks like XML that was exported from a DataSet.   You should be able to read it into a new DataSet....and then bind it to something.